# We do not recognize this tenant ID 21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab75-3cc5ca25846. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again.",

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365api

I want to make multi-tenant application on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.
This work fine with single tenant but 
My process for making multi-tenant app ----
LogIn with Other Tenant and appear consent window and got code successfully which code I passed for getting token

[image: I am getting token from here]

Token successfully generated:
Call graph API for office 365 
But error genrate --
"We do not recognize this tenant ID 21f3be0a-xx-4b7f-ab05-xxxxx6. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again.

[image: I am geeting token from]
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LFDU.png)
When access data for office 365 report why this tenant id not recognized error raised?
Need to edit in manifest ?
My App on  https://apps.dev.microsoft.com.  Have Three 3 Microsoft Graph Permissions
Delegated Permissions - user.read , Reports.Read.All   (Admin Only)

Comment: you should probably remove sensitive data from the screenshot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   I did some mistakes thats why this Error raised then need not do anything becoz this Portal app by default Multitenant and send request to common platform ..
    Login with other tenant get code

    https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?
    client_id=XXXXX-XXX
    &response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=http://localhost:49876    
    &response_mode=query
    &scope=Reports.Read.All 
    &prompt=consent
    &state=12345


    then get token 
    https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
    client_id =XXX
    scope =
    code= which you get
    grant_type=
    client_secret=

    after get token use for Graph API & get office365 data for -https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getMailboxUsageMailboxCounts(period='D7')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [check whether a tenant is valid or invalid](http://shawntabrizi.com/aad/secret-apis-in-azure-active-directory-and-azure-resource-manager/) using the Well Known OpenId Configuration endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

Doing this for your tenant id gives this result:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab75-3cc5ca25846/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

> **error**: "invalid_tenant"
>
> **error_description**: "AADSTS90002: Tenant
>   21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab75-3cc5ca25846 not found. This may happen if
>   there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your
>   subscription administrator.\r\nTrace ID:
>   bdd561b1-bc36-44ce-b3ab-33e53fda0100\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   c6ce0c0d-6550-4f5f-a398-a82f085e28c1\r\nTimestamp: 2017-11-01
>   17:38:31Z"

So simply stated, the tenant id that you are using is not valid for the AAD Worldwide endpoint.

Is it possible you are getting a token for a different instance of AAD? Can you share the [contents of your Access Token](http://shawntabrizi.com/jwt/) (removing any sensitive details)?

Comment: I want to make multi-Tenant  application for getting office 365 data this app work fine with single tenant but I Require multitenantapp ......... Tenant 21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab75-3cc5ca25846 is not correct I changed some digits of Tenant id thats why it showing error but with correct tenant Id it return JSON LIke .....{"authorization_endpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab05-3cc5cad.....so on

Comment: Your issue here is not clear. If the tenant is working, then you are probably getting a different error than what is shown in your pictures. You need to clarify what step of the process you are specifically running into issues.

Comment: Thankyou Shawn Tabrizi for replying me.    I already have one app for single tenant getting office 365 data which work fine, app made on
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com Portal

  But I want to make this multi-tenant app but on this portal(https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) here is no option for making multitenant app ?
can u suggest me how it's possible ?
what r steps ?

Comment: I tried This----
App on apps.dev.microsoft.com Have Three 3 Microsoft Graph Permissions
Delegated Permissions - user.read , Reports.Read.All   (Admin Only)
--Run on browser authorize ---
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=566c0b34-XX-42b3-8ebd-XXXXXXX
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080      
&response_mode=query
&scope=Reports.Read.All
&prompt=consent
&state=12345

Comment: -> LogIn with other tenant concent window appear with Reports.Read.All permission 

------In Postman -----------
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id=566c0b34-XXX-42b3-8ebd-XXXXXX
scope=Reports.Read.All
code= OAQABAAIAAABHh4kmS_aKT5Xr....
redirect_uri =http://localhost:8080
grant_type =authorization_code
client_secret=xlfaFE913aqXXXXIBRV00=|#!

-> Only access_token Genrated 
-> Pass this token for-https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getMailboxUsageMailboxCount(period='D7')

Comment: get This -

"error": {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "We do not recognize this tenant ID 21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab05-3cc5cad25846. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "e9f14fbf-4d92-49dd-95b2-0ca0dc4f6eef",

Comment: Apps from that portal are multi-tenant by default. There is nothing you need to do.

Comment: If it's by default multi-tenant  why I am not getting data for graph API with other tenant login and Got this error ?

Comment: please mark the question as answered if you have your solution @SoumyaMishra