# Issue with accessing reports in Microsoft Graph API - Please double-check the tenant ID and try again

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

When using the graph explorer I am able to get results from some of the API's. However not able to get when requesting for reports

For Example, this works perfectly fine;

```
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

[image]

However, calling the below report related request results in an error "We do not recognize this tenant ID ... Please double-check the tenant ID and try again." I am facing this issue for any such call for reports.

```
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D90')
```

[image]

Is there some issue with App Registration which is causing this? The error message for checking the TenantID is totally misleading as the token is same in both the cases and I am not doing anything different between the two calls. Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking these.

- Try the request after giving some time like 48 hrs approximately as
  it might take a little time for the tenant id to propagate across all
  the instances and reflect in Microsoft graph api.
- [Check if you have given valid tenant ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049020/we-do-not-recognize-this-tenant-id-21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab75-3cc5ca25846-please-d)
- check tenant expiration (as admin account)
- Else check if required permissions are set.

  Reports.Read.All permission is needed  to call this API.Refer [Microsoft
  Graph permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#reports-permissions)

[image]

Please add the Delegated permisson /the Application permission and test it again. See [Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#reports-permissions)

- If that’s done already check if admin consent is  provided .

> (    Reports.Read.All permission  allows an app to read all service
> usage    reports without a signed-in user. Make sure to check if you
> granted    the permission(by clicking Grant Permissions from admin
> account).

See [reports-permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#reports-permissions)

[image]

**References:**

1. [Similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049020/we-do-not-recognize-this-tenant-id-21f3be0a-713c-4b7f-ab75-3cc5ca25846-please-d)
2. [concept-reporting-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-reporting-api)

**Update:**

- This error may occur when the usage report is not ready .Because if
  the tenant is new , it might take sometime( **upto 48 hours**) for
  the report service to pick it up and start generating reports.
- You must be able to test it manually from  [O365 Admin
  Portal](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home?ref=/reportsUsage/LicenseActivity).Portal.office.com -> Admin Tab -> Show all -> Reports ->
  Usage

Other wise , you may contact support to raise a request.